# Mysql Query to get all rows from table except 2

Tags: mysql

In my project i have 3 mysql queries, one for get the info for the next event of the company, one for the info for the previous event and i want to make one for all other events.

The date is given by:
$date=date("Y-m-d");

For the next event i have:
SELECT * FROM passeio WHERE passeio_date > $date LIMIT 0,1

For the previous event i have:
SELECT * FROM passeio WHERE passeio_date < $date LIMIT 0,1

How can i do to get all others rows except the previous and the next event.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a primary key on the table, you can query a combination of above two queries to get all 'other' rows:

```
select * from passeio where ID not in 
(   select * from (
    select ID from passeio where passeio_date > $date LIMIT 0,1
    UNION
    select ID from passeio where passeio_date < $date LIMIT 0,1
    )t
)
```

Comment: It gives me a error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.

Comment: @JoaoCorreia - you are right.Try it now. added a 't'. If it still doesn't work, do a select t.* instead of just a * in the inner query

Answer (score 0):

When using `limit`, you should always include an `order by` if you have a specific ordering in mind.  I think the query you want is:

```
select * from passeio where ID not in 
(   select * from (
    select ID from passeio where passeio_date > $date order by passeio_date asc LIMIT 1
    UNION ALL
    select ID from passeio where passeio_date < $date order by passeio_date desc LIMIT 1
    )t
)
```

I also switched the `union` to a `union all` because you do not need to eliminate duplicates.

Perhaps a more efficient way to do this is:

```
select *
from passeio
where passeio_date > $date
order by passeio_date
limit 1, 1000000000
union all
select *
from passeio
where passeio_date < $date
order by passeio_date desc
limit 1, 1000000000
```

Whether this is more or less efficient depends on the data structure, but it eliminates the anti-join and doesn't require having an ID.